# How to drop a collection with pymongo?

Tags: python, scrapy, pymongo

I use `scarpy` to crawl data and save it to cloud hosting `mLab` successfully with MongoDB.

My collection name is `recently` and data's count is 5.
[image]

I want to crawl data again and update my collection `recently`, so i try to drop the collection and then insert.

Here is my code pipelines.py:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from scrapy.conf import settings

class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        connection = MongoClient(
            settings['MONGODB_SERVER'],
            settings['MONGODB_PORT'])
        db = connection[settings['MONGODB_DB']]
        # here is my collection name recently setting
        self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        # try to drop my collection recently
        self.collection.drop()
        self.collection.insert(dict(item))
        return item
```

But when I run my spider, I see my collection `recently` count is 10 (It should be 5 that is what I want)
[image]

I looking for some code that how to drop collection.
It's just say db.[collection Name].drop()

But its no working in my case when i try `self.collection.drop()` before `self.collection.insert(dict(item))`

Anyone can give me some suggestions what is wrong with my code ?

That would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to use [`drop`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.drop). Suppose `foo` is a collection

```
db.foo.drop()
```

Or you can use `drop_collection`

```
db.drop_collection(collection_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but `self.collection` is db.recently in my case , so i can insert data successfully.

Comment: `insert` worked but `drop` is no working, i run my spider the data count will add 5 every time.

Comment: did you try `self.collection.drop()` or `db.drop_collection(settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'])` @徐博俊

Comment: I have try `db.drop_collection(settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION'])` and `self.collection.drop()` after `self.collection = db[settings['MONGODB_COLLECTION']]` just a moment ago .  It's still add 5 counts  :(

Comment: In your code you are dropping the collection and then inserting some items. So I think count 5 is correct behaviour. Comment out the `self.collection.insert` line and run I am sure it will work. @徐博俊

Comment: I have comment out `self.collection.insert`, the strange things is its still add 5 counts, what the hell with my code...

Comment: The thing was that collection was dropping successfully and you were inserting 5 rows after dropping the collection so you are seeing 5 rows. @徐博俊